# Bad state: A test tried to use any or captureAny on a parameter of type T State using bloc_test and mocktail

Tags: flutter, bloc-test

I tried the solutions in here https://github.com/felangel/mocktail/issues/42 but still get error.
This is my code:

```
class MockUserRepository extends Mock implements UserRepository {}
class MockAuthenticationBloc extends MockBloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> implements AuthenticationBloc {}
class FakeAuthenticationEvent extends Fake implements AuthenticationEvent {}
class FakeAuthenticationState extends Fake implements AuthenticationState {}

void main() {
  MockUserRepository mockUserRepository;
  MockAuthenticationBloc mockAuthenticationBloc;

  setUp(() {
    mockUserRepository = MockUserRepository();
    mockAuthenticationBloc = MockAuthenticationBloc();
    registerFallbackValue(FakeAuthenticationEvent());
    registerFallbackValue(FakeAuthenticationState());
  });

  group('Login', () {
    final username = 'someusername';
    final password = 'somepassword';
    final token = 'sometoken';
    final loginError = 'Some error message.';

    blocTest('emits [LoginLoading] when successful',
      build: () {
        when(() => mockUserRepository.authenticate(username: username, password: password)).thenAnswer((_) async => token);
        return LoginBloc(userRepository: mockUserRepository, authenticationBloc: mockAuthenticationBloc);
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc.add(LoginButtonPressed(username: username, password: password)),
      expect: () => [
        LoginInitial(),
        LoginLoading(),
      ],
    );
  });
}
```

And this is the error:

Bad state: A test tried to use `any` or `captureAny` on a parameter of type `AuthenticationState`, but
registerFallbackValue was not previously called to register a fallback value for `AuthenticationState`.

To fix, do:

```
void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    registerFallbackValue(/* create a dummy instance of `AuthenticationState` */);
  });
}
```

This instance of `AuthenticationState` will only be passed around, but never be interacted with.
Therefore, if `AuthenticationState` is a function, it does not have to return a valid object and
could throw unconditionally.
If you cannot easily create an instance of `AuthenticationState`, consider defining a `Fake`:

```
class MyTypeFake extends Fake implements MyType {}

void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    registerFallbackValue(MyTypeFake());
  });
}
```

What did i miss?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out why your second Register Fallback Value isn't working? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

as said in the docs :

> In order to support argument matchers such as `any()` and `captureAny()` mocktail has to register default fallback values to return when the argument matchers are used. Out of the box, it automatically handles all primitive types, however, when using argument matchers in place of custom types developers must use `registerFallbackValue()` to provide a default return value. It is only required to call `registerFallbackValue()` once per type so it is recommended to place all `registerFallbackValue()` calls within `setUpAll()`.

basically you can only use `any()` or `captureAny()` on **String**,**int**,**double** and other primitive Data Types ,

for using any on a non primitive data type you should register a default value so mocktail knows what to return;

you can create a Fake for ease of use like this

```
class Food {...}

class Cat {
  bool likes(Food food) {...}
}

class MockCat extends Mock implements Cat {}

class FakeFood extends Fake implements Food {}

void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    registerFallbackValue(FakeFood());
  });

  test('...', () {
    final cat = MockCat();
    when(() => cat.likes(any()).thenReturn(true);
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: if you look at the OP's code you can clearly see they registered the fall back values with two classes that extend `Fake` just as the documentation says to do, but it's not registering the second one.